# Android Fragments: Slow loading of data from Database

Tags: android, database, android-fragments

I have a fragmentB with list view . Data in the listview is getting from the local database. When i click on the texview in fragmentA i am opening fragmentB with data from database. But for a fraction of second i could see fragmentA before fragment B is loaded. FragmentB has asyncTask where database query going on. How to avoid this fraction of second delay.

**Code for going to fragmentB from FragmentA**

```
borerangeselect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            BoreRangeFragment boreranges = new BoreRangeFragment();

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                rangeboregrade = boregradeselect.getText().toString();
                if (!rangeboregrade.equalsIgnoreCase("select")) {
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

                    ft.add(R.id.content_frame, boreranges);
                    FragmentChangeActivity.fragmentStack.lastElement().onPause();
                    ft.hide(FragmentChangeActivity.fragmentStack.lastElement());
                    FragmentChangeActivity.fragmentStack.push(boreranges);
                    ft.commit();

                }
            }
        });
```

**FragmentB OnActvitycreated()**

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

            new MyBoreRangeTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,ToleranceFragment.rangeboregrade);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with SQLite then better to use LoaderManagers, they are very easy to use and very efficient while working with db.

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

  public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) { ... }

  public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) { ... }

  public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) { ... }

  /* ... */
}
```

Following is the url of android documentation which you can refer for more information,
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html

Hope this will help you to resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Progress dialog** in onPreExecute method and hide it in doInBackground() method or where your query is ended.
hope it works.